# C#/java android sliding menu from left side

Tags: java, c#, android, menu, slide

In my android app I want a menu that slides in from left side of the screen containing buttons, text and a image. I have tried looking it up on the internet, but I dont quite understand it. I want the menu to slide out on a button click. If someone could explain it or post a example code I would really appreciate it.

The menu I am looking for is something like this:

http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/03/android-sliding-menu-navigation-drawer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `NvigationDrawer` see this link: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html